# Error using geddy auth with MongoDB apapter

Tags: mongodb, geddy

first of all I'm a noob at Geddy so the answer might be something stupid I forgot, but I keep getting an error while using Geddy auth and MongoDB at the same time; Here's what I did:

```
geddy app myapp
```

Then I configured config/development.js to use MongoDB:

```
var config = {
  detailedErrors: true
, debug: true
, hostname: null
, port: 4000
, model: {
    defaultAdapter: 'mongo'
  }
, db: {
  mongo: {
    dbname: 'myappdb'
  }
}
, sessions: {
    store: 'memory'
  , key: 'sid'
  , expiry: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Finally I installed geddy auth and launched the app:

```
geddy auth
geddy
```

When I navigate to localhost:4000/ everything seems to work fine at first, but if I refresh the page or try to create a new user, I get a beautiful Error: 500

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error
Error: db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times
at Db.open (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:240:11)
at open (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:625:20)
at self.connection (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:618:9)
at connection (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:190:18)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:433:13
at cursor (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:158:9)
at self.toArray (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/node_modules/mongodb-wrapper/lib/mongodb-wrapper.js:135:16)
at utils.mixin.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/lib/adapters/mongo/index.js:194:14)
at Object.obj.all (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/lib/index.js:501:25)
at Function.obj.first (/usr/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/model/lib/index.js:459:18)
```

I tried to update geddy using npm and to reinstall the mongo-adapter package but nothing's changed, I'm starting to get really frustrated as I can't find a solution and know it's probably just something simple I'm missing out. 
Any idea of what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't have MongoDB running...
To run your Geddy App you need both things, mongodb and geddy server running.

First of all, start your mongo server:

> $ mongod

And later launch geddy on your root app directory

> $ geddy

Hope that helps